# Make this query safe?

Tags: php, security, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

I have seen some of examples that use something called a PDO to make a query safe from sql-infection, or others that use real_escape, but they all seem to be incomplete or assume some knowledge. So I ask, take this simple update query and make it safe from sql-injection.

```
function updateUserName($id,$first,$last)
{
    $qry = 'UPDATE user SET first = "'.$first.'", last = "'.$last.'" WHERE id = '.$id;
    mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, you have to :

- escape string, with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)
- make sure integer really are integers ; for instance, using [`intval`](http://php.net/intval).

Which, in your specific case, would give something like this :

```
$qry = 'UPDATE user SET first = "'
    . mysql_real_escape_string($first)
    . ' ", last = "'
    . mysql_real_escape_string($last)
    . '" WHERE id = '
    . intval($id);
```

Of course, this is considering that `last` and `first` are varchar, and that `id` is an integer.

As a sidenote : when an SQL error *(this is also true for whatever kind of error you can thing about)* occurs, you should not display a technical error message and just let the script die.

Your users will not understand that technical error message -- they won't know what to do with it, and it's not their problem.

Instead, you should log *(to a file, for instance)* that technical error message, for your own usage ; and display a nice *"oops an error occured"* page to the user.

Answer (score 3):

This is the better query:

```
$qry = 'UPDATE user SET first = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($first).'", last = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($last).'" WHERE id = '.intval($id);
```

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` for strings and `intval` for numbers in your queries to make them safer.

Answer (score 3):

mysql_real_escape_string + sprintf

```
$qry = sprintf('UPDATE user SET first = '%s', last = '%s' WHERE id = %d', mysql_real_escape_string($first), mysql_real_escape_string($last), $id);
```

I like it that way.

Comment: +1 for sprintf which will save you having to do the typing on non-string variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap all your variables in [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). PDO (PHP Data Objects) is a better solution though, if it's available in your environment. You can find these docs [here](https://www.php.net/pdo).

PDO will make your code more Object-Oriented and automate some of these tasks for you. Some good sample code of PDO preparing statements can be found deeper into the docs [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).